# Не работает if else

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Когда условие IF true, ничего нету, хотя должен вывестись логин, а когда срабатывает else то выводится "Нет комментов!". Помогите(

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/connect.php';

$video_id = $_GET['id'];

$comments = mysqli_query(
    $connect, 
    "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE  `video_id` = $video_id"
);

$test = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comments);

if (isset($test)) {

    while($row = $comments->fetch_assoc()) {

        $current_user_id = $row['user_id'];

        $user = mysqli_query(
            $connect, 
            "SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $current_user_id"
        );
    
        while($row_user = $user->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <p><?php echo $row_user['login'];?></p> <?php
        }
    }
} else { ?>
    <p>Нет коммеентов!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p> <?php 
} ?>
```

Comment: Я MySQLi не использую, но похоже, что нужно убрать строку `$test = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comments);` и в услови записать просто: `if ($comments) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` это аналог `$comments->fetch_assoc()`, так что строка `$test = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comments);` не несет смысла, вы просто получаете в `$test` первый результат запроса, и в дальнейшем это может ломать логику внутри блока `if`.

Вместо этого стоит воспользоваться функцией `mysqli_num_rows`, чтобы узнать кол-во найденных записей:

```
$comments = mysqli_query(
    $connect, 
    "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE  `video_id` = $video_id"
);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($comments);

if ($count > 0) {
...
```

НО в данном варианте вообще нет смысла делать запросы в цикле (это плохо), весь код можно объединить в один запрос:

```
SELECT `users`.`login`
FROM `users`
JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `comments`.`video_id` = ?
```

P.S. Используйте подготовленные выражения (https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_prepare.asp) во избежание SQL-инъекций, запихивание данных напрямую в строку с запросом - плохая практика